# Bluedroid crash in GATT main

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

When donging Bluetooth low energy development, doing stress test to connect one central device (phone) with one peripheral device (smart device), found bluedroid crashed in GATT main function with log as below:

```
08-04 11:26:44.915  4155  4190 F libc    : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x1000000 in tid 4190 (bluedroid wake/)

08-04 11:26:44.975  2303  2303 I DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***

08-04 11:26:44.975  2303  2303 I DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 
'marvell/pxa1908FF_tz/pxa1908FF:5.1.1/LMY47V/buildfarm06230955:userdebug/test-keys'

08-04 11:26:44.975  2303  2303 I DEBUG   : Revision: '0'

08-04 11:26:44.976  2303  2303 I DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm'

08-04 11:26:44.976  2303  2303 I DEBUG   : pid: 4155, tid: 4190, name: bluedroid wake/  >>> com.android.bluetooth <<<

08-04 11:26:44.976  2303  2303 I DEBUG   : signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1
 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x1000000

08-04 11:26:44.994  2303  2303 I DEBUG   :     r0 00000001  r1 52aa2c60  r2 00000000  r3 00000001

08-04 11:26:44.994  2303  2303 I DEBUG   :     r4 00000005  r5 4ac2b734  r6 01000000  r7 00000002

08-04 11:26:44.994  2303  2303 I DEBUG   :     r8 00000000  r9 00000000  sl 00000013  fp 00000000

08-04 11:26:44.994  2303  2303 I DEBUG   :     ip 52aa2ba0  sp 52aa2c60  lr 4aacd6c7  pc 01000000  cpsr 600f0010

08-04 11:26:44.995  2303  2303 I DEBUG   : 

08-04 11:26:44.995  2303  2303 I DEBUG   : backtrace:

08-04 11:26:44.995  2303  2303 I DEBUG   :     #00 pc 01000000  <unknown>

08-04 11:26:44.995  2303  2303 I DEBUG   :     #01 pc 000c66c5  
/system/lib/hw/bluetooth.default.so (gatt_add_a_bonded_dev_for_srv_chg+140)

08-04 11:26:44.995  2303  2303 I DEBUG   :     #02 pc 000c6e87  

/system/lib/hw/bluetooth.default.so

08-04 11:26:44.995  2303  2303 I DEBUG   :     #03 pc 000d9c3b  /system/lib/hw/bluetooth.default.so (l2cu_release_lcb+230)

08-04 11:26:44.996  2303  2303 I DEBUG   :     #04 pc 000dbbab  /system/lib/hw/bluetooth.default.so (l2c_link_hci_disc_comp+254)

08-04 11:26:44.996  2303  2303 I DEBUG   :     #05 pc 000d40df  /system/lib/hw/bluetooth.default.so (btu_hcif_process_event+738)

08-04 11:26:44.996  2303  2303 I DEBUG   :     #06 pc 000d4ea3  /system/lib/hw/bluetooth.default.so (btu_task+226)

08-04 11:26:44.996  2303  2303 I DEBUG   :     #07 pc 000a4129  /system/lib/hw/bluetooth.default.so

08-04 11:26:44.996  2303  2303 I DEBUG   :     #08 pc 00016abf  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+30)

08-04 11:26:44.997  2303  2303 I DEBUG   :     #09 pc 000149eb  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+6)

08-04 11:26:45.833  2303  2303 I DEBUG   : 

08-04 11:26:45.833  2303  2303 I DEBUG   : Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_06

08-04 11:26:45.834  2786  2808 I BootReceiver: Copying
 /data/tombstones/tombstone_06 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)

08-04 11:26:45.859  4323  4323 I dumpstate: begin
08-04 11:26:45.838     0     0 E kernel  : [  246.972663] c1 4323 (dumpstate) android: (08-04 11:26:45) process pid: 4155, tid: 4190 crash!
```

Code (gatt_main.c):

```
void gatt_add_a_bonded_dev_for_srv_chg (BD_ADDR bda)
{
    tGATTS_SRV_CHG *p_buf;
    tGATTS_SRV_CHG_REQ req;
    tGATTS_SRV_CHG srv_chg_clt;
    memcpy(srv_chg_clt.bda, bda, BD_ADDR_LEN);
    srv_chg_clt.srv_changed = FALSE;
    if (gatt_add_srv_chg_clt(&srv_chg_clt) != NULL)
    {   
        memcpy(req.srv_chg.bda, bda, BD_ADDR_LEN);
        req.srv_chg.srv_changed = FALSE;
        if (gatt_cb.cb_info.p_srv_chg_callback)
        {
            GATT_TRACE_ERROR("==========abcd xman debug========");          
            (*gatt_cb.cb_info.p_srv_chg_callback)(GATTS_SRV_CHG_CMD_ADD_CLIENT, &req, NULL);
        }
    }
}
```

Did somebody found the similar issue before?
Or if someone give advance?
This test is under android lp5.1.

Comment: Thanks Steven for your kindly help. It's a great help for a newbie.

Comment: I am having the same issue with my Samsung galaxy S4 after I've updated it to Android 5.1 through Cyanogenmod. And I'm not even using bluetooth on my projects! It just randomly crashes.